# Referrences in $L^p$ spaces

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request

I'm learning Real Analysis, and I want to practice some problems about $L^p$ spaces. Can you tell me some problem books or textbooks about it. I known some books such as Problems in Mathematical Analysis III: Integration by Kaczor; Exercises in Integration by C. George.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a list of various books which cover $L^p$ spaces, and have quite a few problems in them :

1. Royden, *Real Analysis*
2. Rudin, *Real and Complex Analysis*
3. Wheeden/Zygmund, *Measure and Integral. An introduction to Real analysis*
4. Folland, *Real Analysis : Modern Techniques and their Applications*

There are many many others of course, but this should get you started.